# Why are some US STAR fixes/waypoints included in FAA's legacy files but not in FAA's published STAR procedures?

Tags: usa, instrument-procedures, sid-star

I have noticed that some US STAR procedures include (slightly) different number of waypoints, depending on which source material is consulted. Take for example the [CAMRN4 STAR](https://web.archive.org/web/20190906004958/https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1908/00610camrn.pdf) and its corresponding description from the legacy files [provided by FAA](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription_2018-03-29/). In the legacy files, the reporting point GAMBY is mentioned between KARRS and CAMRN, whereas in the published information it is omitted.

> S0095  NW N3905438W07448012SIE     SIE.CAMRN4   CAMRN FOUR
>
> S0095  R  N3924521W07427171BOTON K6   S0095  R  N3934583W07416141HOGGS
> K6
>
> S0095  R  N3940336W07410055PANZE K6
>
> S0095  R  N3950271W07359096KARRS K6
>
> S0095  R  N4000222W07352083GAMBY K6
>
> S0095  R  N4001023W07351398CAMRN K6
>
> S0095  AA N4043436W07324483FRG
>
> S0095  AA N4038237W07346433JFK

Is there a reason for this or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: your first link is 404 broken. edit second link also leads to "not found"

Answer (score 1):

Revisions are made to improve traffic flow, adjust for infrastructure(eg local airport change in number of flights or nav beacon decommissioned), simplify procedures for pilots and ATC, or address some other routing conflict or safety issue.
This is why IFR charts and terminal procedures are only valid for two months.

For example there is a victor airway near here that had its MEA raised from 3000 to 5000 because it was discovered that at the lower altitudes something was causing the VOR signal to bend significantly and planes were getting dangerously close to a mountain, I think they may have even had a couple of crashes.